# If statement for variable ending in certain letters

Tags: php

I need a bit of help with this one.

If I have a product ID that is normally a number, but a few ID's end in two letters.

example

Normal 123456
special 123456XD

I want to display something on those special product pages only by using a if statement. So i need to somehow tell say if the product id ends in XD do this.

```
<? if ($id      ):?>
<?=display_cms_data(1)?>
<? endif;?>
```

Above is the beginning of php code , how would I go about asking it if the product $id ends in XD.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Bens answer worked best for my issue:

```
<? if (strlen($id) > 2 && substr($id, -2) == "XD") {  ?> 
<?=display_cms_data(1)?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (preg_match("/[A-Z]+$/", $id)) {
```

would return true for any string ending in at least one of the letters A-Z.

To look for a specific thing, you could do, say,

```
if (strlen($id) > 2 && substr($id, -2) == "XD") {
```

Comment: Ben, thank you very much it seems this way will work, I have some more testing to do on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could just say if the length is five characters do something, else do whatever else you want to do.

Edit: If you want to just look at the last two characters, you could just check length-1 and length-2 to see if they are letters, if they are then you do what you want, else proceed normally.

Comment: I would rather not pigeon whole myself with a length, as there may be more changes in the future. I would rather call for looking at the last two. That way if there is a new one of ZD or QD, etc... I could look for those as well and display something different. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the ones with letters are the only ones which are 7 characters in length, you could call a length function on the $ID and if

--edit

Okay, you said that you didnt want to stick to length.
So, you could call the length function, then get the character in the array (retrieving the last character in the array). You can then compare this character to the ASCII table to see if it is a letter or number. The letters on the ASCII table begin at 42, so if the ASCII code for the last character it greater then 42 it is a letter else if must be a number.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide example code to demonstrate.  Answers are always better with code :)

Answer (score 0):

Following checks whether string ends with two [a-zA-Z] chars regardless of length.

```
$id = (string) $id;
if (strlen($id) >= 2 && ctype_alpha(substr($id, -2)) {
    //Has two alphabetic chars at the end of the string
} else {
    //Doesn't have chars
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the special IDs will always end in 'XD', you can easily use `strlen` and `substr` to write yourself an `endsWith()` function. In very unpythonic Python, it should look like this (Porting to PHP is left as an exercise to the reader):

```
def endsWith(fullStr, subStr):
    return fullStr[len(fullStr) - len(subStr):] == subStr
```

If, however, you want to be able to use arbitrary letters, you may want to look into the regex functions. A regex of `/[A-Z]{2,}$/` would find tell you if your string ends with at least 2 capital letters.